# Does this method of predicting the ratio of translational diffusion coefficients for a sphere and a sheet, work?

Tags: experimental-physics, biophysics

Imagine that I have a spherical particle of molecular weight $M$, volume $V$, and some experimentally observed center-of-mobility translational diffusion coefficient $D_{sphere}$ in water.  I take this sphere and compress it into a sheet with thickness $L$, keeping the $M$ and $V$ constant, and experimentally measure a new translational diffusion coefficient $D_{sheet}$.

Can I ab initio predict the ratio $\frac{D_{sheet}}{D_{sphere}}$?  Does the rigidity of the sheet matter?

Comment: There will not be one ratio. The translational diffusivity becomes anisotropic and gets coupled to a rotational diffusivity.

Comment: Johannes, right, one needs to consider the three mobility tensors.  However, I imagine we should still be able to predict an (experimentally observable) translational diffusion coefficient at the center of mobility.

Comment: On second thought, in the limit of very long times, the disk orientations randomize and the displacement tensor regains an isotropic form. So in that sense a simple ratio will emerge. One needs to solve a not-so-easy hydrodynamic (Stokes flow) problem though.

Comment: Right, if the displacement tensor does not become isotropic, one would be able to create a Feynman brownian ratchet.

Comment: @Johannes You should be able to get this from the ratio of the mobilities of the disk and the sphere instead, shouldn't you? Stokes' drag. Clearly this depends on the orientation of the cylinder, so it's a tensor as opposed to a scalar.

Answer (score 0):

To predict the ratio $\frac{D_{sheet}}{D_{sphere}}$ ab initio, you would need to consider how the shape of the particle affects its diffusion. The Stokes-Einstein relation gives the diffusion coefficient for a spherical particle as:

$$D_{sphere} = \frac{k_B T}{6 \pi \eta r}$$

where $k_B$ is the Boltzmann constant, $T$ is the temperature, $\eta$ is the dynamic viscosity of the fluid, and $r$ is the radius of the sphere. This relation, however, does not apply to non-spherical particles like a sheet.

For non-spherical particles, the diffusion coefficient can be described using the concept of hydrodynamic radius ($r_h$) and an effective friction coefficient ($f_{eff}$):

$$D = \frac{k_B T}{f_{eff}}$$

For a sheet-like particle, $f_{eff}$ will depend on the particle's dimensions and orientation with respect to the flow of the fluid. Assuming the sheet is flat and thin, the ratio $\frac{D_{sheet}}{D_{sphere}}$ will be determined by the ratio of their effective friction coefficients.

The rigidity of the sheet might play a role in the diffusion process if it significantly affects the effective friction coefficient. A more rigid sheet might maintain a more consistent orientation with respect to the fluid flow, whereas a flexible sheet could change its shape and orientation, altering its effective friction coefficient.

In general, predicting the ratio $\frac{D_{sheet}}{D_{sphere}}$ ab initio would require a more detailed analysis of the hydrodynamics involved, taking into account the dimensions of the sheet, its orientation, and possibly its rigidity. Theoretical and computational approaches, such as the method of hydrodynamic interactions or molecular dynamics simulations, could be used to estimate the ratio in specific scenarios.